# Django cache separate database

Tags: database, django, caching

My django project is using separate database and that database has to be cached by using django cache. So the way is not straight forward.

I read in [djangoproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#database-caching-and-multiple-databases) but I could not understand.  The link shows a model "CacheRouter" with some defs.

I am not sure whether it is 
sample code or

- the code already present somewhere or
- the code I have to alter or
- the code I have to add in my models.

Can anyone explain elaborately ?

Comment: I'm not sure what question you're asking or problem you're having… Can you clarify?

Comment: I am manually selecting separate database and that database needs to be cached.
Do I need to write ROUTER ?
If YES, where ? models.py ? And how will the settings.py know ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a generic router, which is configured using a `dict` of the apps that go to a non-default database.

```
app_to_database = {
    'django_cache': 'the_declared_name_of_the_cache_database',
}

class CacheRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return app_to_database.get(model._meta.app_label, None)

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return app_to_database.get(model._meta.app_label, None)

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        _db = app_to_database.get(model._meta.app_label, None)
        return db == _db if _db else None
```

**Edit: better explanation**

If you want to use different schemas, or database servers or even differnet backends altogether, you need to declare them in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': # the one storing your app data
        { 'NAME': 'main_db', # this is the schema name
          'USER': '...',
          'PASSWORD': '...',
          'ENGINE': '...', # etc...
        },
    'the_declared_name_of_the_cache_database': # the name is arbitrary here
        { 'NAME': 'db_for_djcache', # this is the schema name
          'USER': '...',
          'PASSWORD': '...',
          'ENGINE': '...', # etc...
        },
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.MyAppRouter'] # that is, the module.ClassName of the
                                           # router class you defined above.
```

If, on the other side, as you seem to imply from your comment, you only need a different table (inside the same schema), you don't need a router at all, everything is managed smoothly by django.

You can check what happens using any GUI client to the database. Just open your schema(ta) and check the tables and their content.

Comment: I believe we use a seperate table for cache. So, what shall I put in "the_declared_name_of_the_cache_database"?

Then do I need to write this code in my app.models.py ?
IF so, how settings.py will know this code ?

Comment: OKAY, If I add this CacheRouter, how will I know this is working ?
How to check it ?